# Como instanciar uma classe em php utilizando um array como argumento (igual faz com call_user_func_array)?

Tags: php

No php, quando eu posso invocar uma função, utilizando um `array` como se eu estivesse passando cada argumento em sequência.

Exemplo:

```
  function soma_a_b($a, $b)
  {
        return $a + $b;
  }
```

Se eu tivesse um array com dois elementos, eu poderia fazer de duas formas. Assim:

```
    $array = [4, 6];

    soma_a_b($array[0], $array[1]);
```

Ou assim:

```
  call_user_func_array('soma_a_b', $array);
```

Isso também funciona para métodos de classes. Por exemplo:

```
class Soma
{
      public function resultado($a, $b)
      {
          return $a + $b;
      }
}


$soma = new Soma;

call_user_func_array([$soma, 'resultado'], $array);
```

Quando o método da classe é estático, podemos fazer de duas formas:

```
  call_user_func_array('Soma::resultado', $array);

  call_user_func_array(['Soma', 'resultado'], $array);
```

Isso é algo muito bom, pois trás dinamismo para trabalhar com alguns métodos ou funções.

Porém eu preciso dessa funcionalidade ao criar uma instância da classe. Ou seja, no construtor.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
 call_user_func_array(['ArrayObject', '__construct'], [1, 2]);
```

Mas isso dá erro, pois o `__construct` não é estático.

> PHP warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method ArrayObject::__construct() cannot be called statically

Eu sei que existe como fazer isso  nas versões iguais ou superiores ao `PHP 5.6`.

Basta usar o `variadic args`:

```
 class Carro
 {
       public function __construct($tipo, $ano)
       {}
 }

 $args = ['Tipo', '2015'];

 $soma = new Soma(...$args);
```

Porém, eu uso ainda o PHP 5.4. Então o exemplo acima não vai funcionar.

Existe alguma maneira de instanciar uma classe em PHP, usando um `array` como lista de argumentos, da mesma forma que é feita com `call_user_func_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar Reflection para construir uma instância de uma classe passando os parâmetros como um array.

```
<?php
  $class = new ReflectionClass('Carro');
  $instance = $class->newInstanceArgs(array('fiat', '2012'));
?>
```

O método newInstanceArgs irá chamar o construtor mesmo que você passe um array vazio. Se a classe não tiver construtor ela irá jogar uma Exception.

Comment: Parabéns, meu filho. Você foi rápido no gatilho :D +1

Comment: Se você quiser simplificar essa treta aí, pode fazer assim (PHP 5.4 >=) `$carro = (new ReflectionClass('Carro'))->newInstanceArgs(['Fiat', '2012'])`

Comment: Hum... Gostei da última informação da `Exception`. Então é bom usar o método `getConstructor` e verificar se é null antes :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, Exato.